# Conflicting versions between Gradle groovy and RestAssured groovy

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, rest-assured

I'm trying to run an automated test that uses the RestAssured useRelaxedHTTPSValidation() method, but execution blows up with the following error message.

I'm using gradle for my build, and this is and old project I'm trying to resurrect.

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-xml is loaded in version 2.5.8 and you are trying to load version 3.0.8
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:524)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModulesFrom(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    ... 15 more
```

ADDITIONAL INFO: this is my gradle.build file, maybe there's some dependency issue I'm not realizing

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

//buildScan { termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"; termsOfServiceAgree = "yes" }
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.4.0'
    compile group: 'com.codeborne', name: 'selenide', version: '5.6.1'
    compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '7.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.github.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '7.3.0' // should have the same version as io.appium java-client

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.19'

    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '4.2.0'
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '4.2.0'
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-path', version: '4.2.0'
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'xml-path', version: '4.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.2'
    compile group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '3.0.0'

    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.26'

    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-selenide', version: '2.15.0'
    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-rest-assured', version: '2.15.0'
    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.15.0'
}

allure {
    version = '2.15.0'
    autoconfigure = true
    aspectjweaver = true
    allureJavaVersion = '2.15.0'
}
```

In the same file, below, I have some automated testng tasks

Comment: Which version of Gradle, and do you have a simple reproducer project that shows the issue?

Comment: I'm using gradle 7.2 on my PC, but my gradle.properties file on the project has the following line: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip. I've been working with the build.gradle file, and this used to work perfectly before.

Comment: You're running with `gradlew`?

Comment: run this command to update the gradle wrapper:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.3 --distribution-type all
```

It's possible that your plugins are updated for newer Gradle versions, hence you need to make sure to use an updated Gradle distribution. Your build is using lots of deprecated stuff, but it should probably still work anyway.

Comment: If you declared the version of the allure plugin (it might be declared in `settings.gradle`, if it is, we can figure out which version of Gradle it was built for), it might have worked fine when you ran the build with `./gradlew ...`... but almost certainly, the right thing to do is make sure you're using the latest version of that plugin (https://docs.qameta.io/allure-report/reporting/gradle) and of Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with dependencies. When RestAssured methods were executed, the groovy version associated to it was older than the one already being executed. I navigated with the my CLI to the directory where the gradle files are located, executed "gradle -dependencies", and updated the dependencies based on what gradle told me to. After this it started working.

Comment: Did you actually mean the `gradle -q dependencies` command as per [Listing dependencies in a project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies)?